# GH Pages loading incorrect React Router Page?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I have a small React app that when deployed with GH-Pages is loading my error component on page load as opposed to my home page?

Could anyone please explain why this is?

Route

```
<Router>
     <Navbar />
     <Switch>
       <Route exact path = "/">
         <Home />
       </Route>
       <Route path = "/about">
         <About />
       </Route>
       <Route path = "/cocktail/:id">
         <SingleCocktail />
       </Route>
       <Route path = "*">
         <Error />
       </Route>
     </Switch>
   </Router>
```

Comment: In GH-Pages make sure you use the [`HashRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter) instead of any other due to the server config there

Comment: I have no idea how to do that but im sure ill find the documentation. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the server config of GitHub pages you will need to use the [`HashRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter) in your app. Your GitHub pages url will likely come with a path after the main URL which is why the `*` is triggered in your route.

To do this all you have to do is replace the router you import right now with `HashRouter`:

Instead of:

```js
// import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

You change it to:

```js
import { HashRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

The rest of your code can remain as is. (Most likely)

Comment: Easy as that. Thank you!